# In python, how to execute a file, print its output in real time and resume current process afterwards?

Tags: python

In python,

**`os.exec..`** commands replace the current process. For example following script

```
import os, time

print 'before calling'
os.execv('test.py', ['test.py'])
print 'after calling'
```

won't print "after calling"

**`commands.getoutput`** returns the output as a string.
I want to print the output in real time line by line snice my other executable takes long time and prints a lot to stdout.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: check [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: read this http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import subprocess

print 'before calling'
subprocess.call(["python", "test.py"])
print 'after calling'
```

Where `test.py` is

```
print "hello!"
```

Outputs:

```
before calling
hello!
after calling
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
print 'before'
import test
print 'after'
```

Take a look at [`execfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile).

This does not clutter your modulenamespace and does what you ask for.

I don't know why you need to do this, but have you considered providing functions in your ohther file which you call? Why do you need to execute a file directly?